# Loop through all worksheets to find bottom-most row of data in each tab individually

Tags: vba, excel

I found this cool code that identifies the bottom-most row of data in a worksheet (considering all columns), and then types an X in Column B of the following row.

However I have been unsuccessful at creating a loop with this code, so that each worksheet is treated uniquely. My attempts have typed X in the same cell of all worksheets, but not each worksheet individually based on it's own set of data.
Also note that each of my tabs will not always have the same column be the longest, which is why I needed a code to look across all columns to find the bottom-most row.

Can someone suggest how I can loop this and identify the bottom-most row in each worksheet individually?

```
Sub EndofData()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

iRow = Cells.Find(What:=”*”, _
After:=Range(“A1”), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

Cells(iRow + 1, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = “x”

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to do a For Each Loop:

```
Sub EndofData()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As range
Dim iCol As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

   set iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=" * ", _
    After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False)

    If not irow is nothing then        
        ws.Cells(iRow.Row + 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "x"
    Else 
        ws.Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "x"
    End IF
Next ws

End Sub
```

Thanks to @Darren for help on the error avoidance.

Comment: I'm getting a Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: I added a "On Error Resume Next" clause and it seems to be working on most sheets. Is there something that would trigger it to not work on some sheets?

Comment: No do not add "On Error Resume Next".  You need to find out why there is an error on those sheets and deal with it in the code.  I believe that there is no data anywhere on those sheets that throw the error so irow is nothing.  I will edit my code to deal with that.

Comment: That'll still throw an error as iRow is a long to hold the row number.  Find the cell, if that's not nothing then get the row number from it otherwise set the row number as 1.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook isn't that what I just did with the if statement, if irow is is nothing it will put the "x" in B1 and ignore irow completely?

Comment: `If Not iRow Is Nothing` throws a `Type Mismatch` as iRow is a Long. If you change it to a Range then the .Find command will throw an `Object variable or With block variable not set` error as you're asking it to return the row number rather than the range reference.

Comment: I'd create a new variable to hold the range reference in the .Find command and then use something like: `If LC Is Nothing Then: iRow = 1: Else: iRow = LC.Row: End If`

Comment: @FaithMitchell see edit it should do every sheet now.

Comment: @FaithMitchell if this is the correct answer please mark the answer as correct. it is something only you can do.  click on the green check mark by the answer.